# Shared members static or dynamic memory allocation C++

Tags: c++

I have been reading C++ Primer the past few days and I have run into a confusing problem. In the book it states that in order to share a member variable between objects of the same class, we have to use dynamic memory allocation. I was wondering though, can't we also use the static keyword to achieve the same?

Comment: You can use both, dependent on your needs. Static member variable is visible in ALL instances of your class, whereas you will need some mechanismus to share the pointer to the dynamic memory, problably some depencency injection. But consider problems with soft/deep copy, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference lies between whether you want to share the (member) object between **all** or **some** instances of your class.

Static members are shared between **all** instances, i.e. they are not coupled to instances at all. They exist once and only once (even if there is no instance at all).

But there are cases where you want to share the same member object between **some** instances. Think of a tree data structure. The parent node reference is a perfect example: All siblings share the same parent. The parent is not allocated *within* each sibling; that would mean it exists multiple times which would be wrong. We typically use pointers or references to point to the parent node indirectly; in C++11 (or for previous standards by using a library) we have weak or shared smart pointers for this.

Answer (score 1):

You *could*, but that serves a whole other purpose and in general is not a good thing to use anyway. What the book probably meant is to have shared data possibly of unknown size between some or all of the objects. If nothing, at least it probably wanted to discourage you from using `static` member variables.